# Error 403 Forbidden for Proxy

Tags: linux, selenium

When I try to run the selenium server on a Centos OS 7 linux box: I get the following error when trying to curl localhost:4444

```
Error 403 Forbidden for Proxy
```

Does anyone know why?

I run the selenium server by doing

```
DISPLAY=:1 xvfb-run java -jar /home/jenkins-user/tools/selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/home/jenkins-user/tools/chromedriver &
```

When I curl http://localhost:4444/ I get the error above

Comment: Is this the only log you are getting, also how do you run selenium server and what configs are you using shall be of use in the question details.

Comment: Also what url are you using to connect to the remote server? It should ideally be `http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub`

Comment: answered abve. see above

Comment: If you start the grid by using the command "java -jar <selenium-server***.jar>" then
you will get "HTTP 403 Forbidden for Proxy" error.

Start the grid using the command "java -jar <selenium-server**.jar> -role hub". Now
navigating to http://localhost:4444/console should work

Comment: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/592 this might help

Comment: I don't want to create a hub/grid. I just want the server to run